# Rails - PG Foreign Key Violation on DELETE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application that has `Venues` and `Clients`.

Each venue has many clients:

```ruby
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
end
```

When I try to delete some venue, Postgres complains about foreign key constraint violation:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "venues" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_3afaf2f5fc" on table "clients" DETAIL: Key (id)=(3) is still referenced from table "clients". : DELETE FROM "venues" WHERE "venues"."id" = $1
```

It would be simple to solve by adding `dependent: :destroy` to the association.

But I want to keep the clients, even if they have no more venue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use nullify. It will set `venue_id` on clients to null. But you need to remove foreign key constraint from the column.

```
has_many :clients, dependent: :nullify
```

Comment: Perfect! just what I needed.